# Access the result of a previous calculation in custom function passed to apply()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm working with Pandas in Python and I would like to access the result of the previous calculation when applying a custom function to a series.

Roughly like this:

```
import pandas

# How can I obtain previous_result?
def foo(value, previous_result = None):

    # On the first iteration there is no previous result
    if previous_result is None:
        previous_result = value

    return value + previous_result

series = pandas.Series([1,2,3])
print(series.apply(foo))
```

This can also be generalized to "How to pass the `n` previous results to the function?". I know about `series.rolling()` but even with rolling I wasn't able to obtain the previous *results*, only the previous values of the input series.

Comment: Instead of describing this via a pseudocode, a small working example (input/desired output) would really simplify things up.

Comment: That's not pseudo code - if you replace the `previous_result` parameter. I'm looking for such a working example :)

Comment: That's still unclear to me, too. An example wouldn't hurt. Is it possible that you are looking for `expanding` but not `rolling`?

Comment: I want to do a calculation like `f(x) = x + f(x-1)` on a Pandas series. Does it explain what I'm trying? Can you give an example how `expanding` can be used here?

Comment: For example you can do something like `ser.expanding().apply(lambda r: reduce(lambda prev_result, value: prev_result+2*value, r))` It is equivalent to `f(x) = 2x + f(x-1)` In Python 3 you'll need `from functools import reduce`

Comment: @ayhan That sounds promising! Let me try that. I'll AFK but back later

Comment: @ayhan That worked for me. Thank you! (You may post it as an answer)

Comment: But one thing, while it works, it is not efficient. It needs to perform the calculations again and again with an increasing number of elements. The window I need for my calculation just needs two values: [result from previous row, current row].

Comment: Btw, I want to perform [exponential smoothing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_smoothing#Basic_exponential_smoothing). I know `Pandas.ewma` but wanted to do it manually for educational purposes. Probably I should have a look at the code of `Pandas.ewma`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most special type of the operations you describe are available as `cummax`, `cummin`, `cumprod`  and `cumsum` (`f(x) = x + f(x-1)`).

More functionality can be found in [`expanding`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.expanding.html) objects: mean, standard deviation, variance kurtosis, skewness, correlation, etc.

And for the most general case, you can use `expanding().apply()`  with a custom function. For example,

```
from functools import reduce  # For Python 3.x
ser.expanding().apply(lambda r: reduce(lambda prev, value: prev + 2*value, r))
```

is equivalent to `f(x) = 2x + f(x-1)`

The methods I listed are optimized and run quite fast but when you use a custom function the performance gets worse. For exponential smoothing, pandas starts to outperform loops for Series of length 1000 but `expanding().apply()`'s performance with reduce is quite bad:

```
np.random.seed(0)    
ser = pd.Series(70 + 5*np.random.randn(10**4))    
ser.tail()
Out: 
9995    60.953592
9996    70.211794
9997    72.584361
9998    69.835397
9999    76.490557
dtype: float64


ser.ewm(alpha=0.1, adjust=False).mean().tail()
Out: 
9995    69.871614
9996    69.905632
9997    70.173505
9998    70.139694
9999    70.774781
dtype: float64

%timeit ser.ewm(alpha=0.1, adjust=False).mean()
1000 loops, best of 3: 779 µs per loop
```

With loops:

```
def exp_smoothing(ser, alpha=0.1):
    prev = ser[0]
    res = [prev]
    for cur in ser[1:]:
        prev = alpha*cur + (1-alpha)*prev
        res.append(prev)
    return pd.Series(res, index=ser.index)

exp_smoothing(ser).tail()
Out: 
9995    69.871614
9996    69.905632
9997    70.173505
9998    70.139694
9999    70.774781
dtype: float64

%timeit exp_smoothing(ser)
100 loops, best of 3: 3.54 ms per loop
```

Total time is still in milliseconds but with `expanding().apply()`:

```
ser.expanding().apply(lambda r: reduce(lambda p, v: 0.9*p+0.1*v, r)).tail()
Out: 
9995    69.871614
9996    69.905632
9997    70.173505
9998    70.139694
9999    70.774781
dtype: float64

%timeit ser.expanding().apply(lambda r: reduce(lambda p, v: 0.9*p+0.1*v, r))
1 loop, best of 3: 13 s per loop
```

Methods like `cummin`, `cumsum` are optimized and only require x's current value and function's previous value. However with a custom function the complexity is `O(n**2)`. This is mainly because there will be cases that function's previous value and x's current value won't be enough to calculate function's current value. For cumsum, you can use previous cumsum and add the current value to reach a result. You cannot do that for, say, geometric mean. That's why `expanding` will become unusable for even moderately sized Series.

In general, iterating over a Series is not a very expensive operation. For DataFrames, it needs to return a copy of each row so it is very inefficient but this is not the case for Series. Of course you should use vectorized methods when available but if that's not the case, using a for loop for a task like recursive calculation is OK.

Comment: Many thanks for this detailed answer! Good to hear from an expert that a loop is not a so bad solution with Pandas - if no standardized method can be used.